# Rails app with postgresql; query with .take does not keep the order of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I have a rails 4 application and I recently switched from SQlite to Postgresql. I have the following 3 models;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_games
    has_many :games, :through => :user_games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_games
    has_many :users, :through => :user_games
end

class UserGame < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :game
end
```

with the records:

```
game
id
1 

userGame
id  user_id   game_id
1      5         1
2      3         1

user
id
1
2
```

I could do this with sqlite:

```
game = Game.Find(1)
game.users.take(2).first
```

which would return User with id 5.

The same code with postgres gives user with id 3.

Why?

EDIT:

I forgot to add that I need to get the users in the order they appear in the table.

So if...

```
game
id
1 
2

userGame
id  user_id   game_id
1      5         1
2      3         1
3      1         2
4      4         2

user
id
1
2
3
4
```

... I need a query that preserves the order of the users, so that `game1.users.first.id = 5` and `game2.users.first.id = 1`

`game1.users.take(2).first.id` would preserve this order when I used sqlite, but with postgresql it does not.

Comment: `game.users.order('users.id ASC').limit(2).first`..

Comment: This works, but not for the edited part that I forgot to include. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[take](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take) has the following explanation in manual:

### Take

```
Gives a record (or N records if a parameter is supplied) without any
implied order. The order will depend on the database implementation. If
an order is supplied it will be respected.
```

If you want to get the same result with Postgresql and with Sqlite specify a default order.

```
game.users.order('users.id DESC').first
```

Or since `last` and `first` method` sorts your data in Rails 4 use:

```
game.users.last
```

This will translate into the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE "games"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

My conclusion is that you don't need to use take at all

**Edit**

You have:

```
game = Game.find(1)
users = game.users.order("user_games.id ASC").take(2)
```

Then, if you iterate over your `users` collection:

```
users.each do |user|
  puts user.inspect
end
```

you should get those users ordered as you want.

Comment: I edited my question. Your solution works, but not to the part I had not mentioned. Sorry about that